# aiohttp: chain of decorators sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine, aiohttp

Consider the following code:

```
from aiohttp_mako import template

def authorize():
    def wrapper(func):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            allowed = # Some auth stuff
            if not allowed:
                return HTTPUnauthorized()
            return func()
        return wrapped
    return wrapper


@authorize()
@template('admin.mak')
async def admin(request):
    return dict(ok=True)
```

I expect `authorize()`' `wrapper` to get `template` decorator as its `func` 
so I can return the `Response` it generates in my `authorize` decorator. But `authorize()`' `wrapper` takes the `admin()` coroutine as the `func` and it ends up with

```
File "/Users/etemin/virtualenvs/onlinelux/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 306, in _handle
    resp = yield from handler(request)
File "/Users/etemin/virtualenvs/onlinelux/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp_session/__init__.py", line 134, in middleware
    raise RuntimeError("Expect response, not {!r}", type(response))
RuntimeError: ('Expect response, not {!r}', <class 'generator'>)
```

Cause it tries to return the coroutine. How should I make it to return the `template` decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrapped a co-routine, so you need to *await* that co-routine (yield from it):

```
def authorize():
    def wrapper(func):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            allowed = # Some auth stuff
            if not allowed:
                return HTTPUnauthorized()
            return yield from func()
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

Since you are already using the `async`/`await` syntax, I'd just use that here too and not use `@asyncio.coroutine`:

```
def authorize():
    async def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def wrapped(*args):
            allowed = # Some auth stuff
            if not allowed:
                return HTTPUnauthorized()
            return await func()
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

Note that I awaited on `func()` there, and returned the result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I encountered something really strange for me. The `yield` syntax raises `RuntimeError: ('Expect response, not {!r}', <class 'NoneType'>)` but the same `async/await` syntax works well! How come?

Comment: @Juggernaut: ah, forgot a `return`, added in now. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me**.

Inspired from [@aiohttp_csrf.csrf_protect](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-csrf/).

```py
from functools import wraps

from aiohttp import web


def is_authorized(request):
    # Write logic to validate request
    return True


def authorize(handler=None):  # When python module having view was imported, it expected to have this.

    def wrapper(handler):
        @wraps(handler)
        async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            request = args[-1]

            if isinstance(request, web.View):
                # Should also work for Class-Based Views
                request = request.request

            try:
                is_authorized(request)
            except Exception as ex:
                # request not authorized. Write logic to handle it accordingly
                print('Request not authorized: ', repr(ex))
                raise ex

            response = await handler(*args, **kwargs)
            return response

        return wrapped

    if handler is None:
        return wrapper

    return wrapper(handler)
```

Somewhere in your view:

```py
@authorize()
@template('admin.mak')
async def admin(request):
    return dict(ok=True)
```